# How to check input validation using Ajax connect to database (jsp)

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom-events, onsubmit

The code is to check if the university input from user already exists in database. If yes, then submit the input and go to the next page; if not, then send user an alert message and stay on the same page, which is choose_university.jsp. The checkUniversity.jsp is used to connect to the database and do the checking.
But the code is not doing it. I have spent hours on it and still can't figure it out. Could anyone please tell me what's wrong with it and show me how to fix it? It's due tomorrow. Please help me.

choose_university.jsp is following:

```
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>

 <html>
 <head><title>Provide degrees - choose university</title> 
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function validate() {

     var xmlHttp;
     xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     if (xmlHttp == null) {
     alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
     return;
      }
     var u = document.getElementById("university").value;
     var url = "checkUniversity.jsp";
     url = url + "?university=" + u;
     xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 ) {
          document.getElementById("university").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
     }
     alert("yea we got 55555");
     xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
     xmlHttp.send(null);
  }



  function GetXmlHttpObject() {
      var xmlHttp = null;
      try {
          // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari

           xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } catch (e) {
            // Internet Explorer
     try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
     } catch (e) {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }
     }
     return xmlHtp;
  }
   </script>
   </head>
    <body>
   <br> If you can't find your university, please provide it in the following and hit submit <br>
   <form method="post" action="Provide_degrees_Choose_discipline.jsp" onsubmit = "return validate()">
    <p>To manually add your university </p> <br>
    <p> name of university: <input type = "text" id="university"  name = "university" />        </p><br>
    <input type="submit" name = "submit" value="submit"  />
    </form>
     </body>
     </html>



       /*  checkUniversity.jsp  */
      <% response.setContentType("text/xml") ; %>

     <%@ page import="javax.sql.*"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean"%>
      <%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%>
      <%@ page import="model.ApplicationModel" %>
    <html>
     <head><title>check university</title> 
    </head>
     <body>
     <%
          System.out.println("heyheyhey");

           String u = request.getParameter("university") ;
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        // Open a connection to the database using DriverManager
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/access?" +
                "user=postgres&password=neshorange");
        // Create the statement
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            // Use the created statement to SELECT
            // the student attributes FROM the Student table.

        rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) as c FROM universities WHERE university=\'"+ u +"\';");
      if (rs.next()){
       if ( rs.getInt("c") > 0) {
           response.write("false");
       } else {
       response.write("true");
       }
      }
       response.write("true");
        %>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Is the problem that your server code doesn't get called, that it does get called but doesn't work, or that the server-side works but the client doesn't process the result correctly? I'd suggest you cut the checkUniversity.jsp code down to the bare minimum to always return a positive result - as close to a one-liner JSP as you can make it. Once you have that working with the JavaScript try it with a hardcoded negative result and be sure that works in the JavaScript too. Only then put back the SELECT statement and so forth.

Comment: Also, why aren't you using the `GetXmlHttpObject()` function? Are you sure you want checkUniversity.jsp to use a response content type of "text/xml"? Why is your checkUniversity.jsp outputting a full html page with head and body elements given that it is for an ajax request where you seem to just want "true" or "false"?

Comment: what do you see in the firebug

Comment: There is no error message. I think the checkUniversity.jsp just doesn't get called at all. I did try to just have checkUniversity.jsp return true or false, but then I don't know how to deal with it in the validate() function. What should I put after the xmlHttp.send(null) in order to deal with the return value of checkUniversity.jsp, like if(returnValue(checkUniversity.jsp) == true ) { return true; } else return false. ?

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the "return" in your onSubmit and try again. Also install firebug or another inspector (if you haven't already) so you can see javascript and request errors.

Also these days there is no need to go through all the ajax stuff like this. Look at javascript libraries like jQuery or Mootools. They can turn you js code into only a few lines.

Comment: I can't. Because this is an assignment of a class.I tried this. But it's still not working. The checkUniversity.jsp still doesn't get called. And I still don't know how to deal with the return value of checkUniversity.jsp (assume it gets called correctly, ), which is either "true" or "false" in string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function validate()
{
    var u = document.getElementById("university").value;
    $.post('checkUniversity.jsp?university=' + u, function(data) {
      if(data==true) return true;
      else
          {
              alert("user doesnot exists ")
              return false;
          }
});
}
```

You have return true if users exists from checkUniversity.jsp

Comment: I think this is homework, so jQuery probably isn't allowed (or it would've been mentioned in the question).

Comment: Right, it's not allowed. I tried this. But it's still not working. The checkUniversity.jsp still doesn't get called. And I still don't know how to deal with the return value of checkUniversity.jsp (assume it gets called correctly, ), which is either "true" or "false" in string.

Comment: is it going for another page google.com and try to display it in your div